# Problems with Evolution installation

Tags: installation, evolution

I tried to install Evolution in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS through Ubuntu Software Center, but ran into an error saying "Package dependencies cannot be resolved"

Error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

evolution: Depends: evolution-common (= 3.2.3-0ubuntu6) but 3.2.3-0ubuntu6 is to be installed

What does this error mean? Is 3.2.3-0ubuntu6, a version of Ubuntu?. I have been facing some or the other error in installing software from Software Center. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Package: evolution (3.2.3-0ubuntu6) are the groupware suite with mail client and organizer. you can read more about here - http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/evolution

You can resolve the evolution dependencies by Download Page for **evolution_3.2.3-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb on AMD64 machines**

If you are running Ubuntu, it is strongly suggested to use a package manager like aptitude or synaptic to download and install packages, instead of doing so manually via this website.

You should be able to use any of the listed mirrors by adding a line to your /etc/apt/sources.list like this:

```
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ precise main
```

more info visit: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/evolution/download

Download Page for **evolution_3.2.3-0ubuntu6_i386.deb on Intel x86 machines**

If you are running Ubuntu, it is strongly suggested to use a package manager like aptitude or synaptic to download and install packages, instead of doing so manually via this website.

You should be able to use any of the listed mirrors by adding a line to your /etc/apt/sources.list like this:

```
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ precise main
```

more info visit: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/evolution/download

try to solve dependencies by download suitable package.